# Как вывести диалоговое окно в сервисе?

Tags: c#, служба

Есть служба, написанная мной. В сервисе я использовал стороннюю библиотеку. Дело в том, что из библиотеки вызывается форма. Соответственно у меня исключение. *Показ модального диалогового окна или формы является допустимой операцией, только если приложение запущено в режиме UserInteractive. Для отображения уведомления из служебного приложения укажите стиль ServiceNotification или DefaultDesktopOnly.*
Мне нужно, чтобы данное сообщение выводилось. Есть ли пример как это сделать?В настройках самой службы "Разрешить взаимодействие с рабочим столом" не решает проблему. Если что-то не точно написал - спрашивайте. Всем спасибо.

Comment: я бы выкинул все лишнее из службы. для того чтоб взаимодействовать с пользователем можно запустить агента в трей

Comment: Чисто из службы интерфейс никак не показать. В таких случаях делают обычно агента - второе приложение, которому служба посылает сообщения